# Do I need a transaction for multiple queries in one string?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp

```
SQLite::Database    db("example.db3");
while(...)
{
    db.exec("INSERT INTO xxx VALUES(...)");
}
```

It's sample code for SQLite to insert data. If there's no transaction, each `db.exec` is slow, almost takes 1 second.

So, you need a transaction :

```
db.exe("BEGIN");
while(...)
{
    db.exec("INSERT INTO xxx VALUES(...)");
}
db.exe("END");
```

But if I make all queries into one string:

```
db.exec("INSERT INTO xxx VALUES(...);\
INSERT INTO xxx VALUES(...);\
INSERT INTO xxx VALUES(...);\
...
");
```

Do I still need a transaction?

Comment: "Do I still need a transaction?" - that depends on what you need/want. Do you need or want all `INSERT`s to be atomic with regards to other readers? If yes, then you need a transaction, if no, then you probably don't.

Comment: In SQLite, using a transaction for bulk INSERT is **much, much master**. On Windows, it is nearly 100x faster, the difference is less but still very significant on macOS or Linux. Therefore, I suggest to *always* use transaction for bulk INSERT.

Comment: In this case you are still doing multiple insert statements so I would expect you to need a transaction for performance reasons. If you inserted multiple rows in 1 insert I believe you don't: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16592427/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16592427/487892)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert 'everything' or 'nothing', then, YES. You still need a transaction. `SQLite::Database::exec()` internally calls `sqlite3_exec()` and semicolon separated SQL statement will not be executed atomically without a transaction.